# C++: convert char * to wstring

Tags: c++, string, utf-8, wstring

Arguments in `argv[]` are UTF-8 encoded. I would like to do something like:

```
#include <wstring>
#include <???>

void doWhatever(wstring &ws);

using ???;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    while (--argc)
    {
        // Convert argv to wstring
        wstring ws = ???(argv[argc]);
        doWhatever(ws);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The `???` I don't know. I'm sure this is trivial for C++ people, but searching it just brings up a lot of noise.

Comment: [`std::wstring_convert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert)

Comment: Are you sure they are UTF-8? Because on winows, they aren't...

Comment: `$ locale`
`LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: @chris - Wow, huge learning curve for this function! Do you know of any sample code, I can just plug it in?

Comment: @YiminRong, I've never had the chance to use it, so no. Mostly a case of libstdc++ not supporting it (last I checked anyway). However, [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16) looks pretty relevant. Turns out [libc++ supports it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4ee65ac8a6645ae), too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That a very good question! :-)

1. As Maxim wrote: mbstowcs()
2. wsprintf() with "%S" (Capital "S"). In wsprintf() "S" means multi-byte string (in sprintf() "S" means wide-char).
3. You can use std::wstring_convert and choose the UTF-8 encoding. I THINK its "codecvt_utf8_utf16"

For windows:

1. MultiByteToWideChar() in WINAPI
2. If you set to the clipboard using SetClipboardData() the ASCII text using CF_TEXT, windows allows you to GetClipboardData() for CF_UNICODETEXT doing the conversion for you!

You can also do it hardcore manually (and work only in some of the cases) by adding "NULLs" between 2 ASCII characters.

That's all comes to mind right now :-)

Answer (score 0):

On UNIX/Linux use [iconv](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/iconv.3.html).

On Windows use [mbstowcs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1f9b8cy.aspx).

There is also a [standard C++ mbstowcs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbstowcs), but its interface is a bit lacking.